Why is my Opensearch query returning results in the wrong order?
I'm using Opensearch to retrieve some documents from my index. Here is the query I'm using:
PUT /your_index
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 3,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ts_id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "myid": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}


PUT /your_index/_doc/3
{
  "myid": "1",
  "ts_id": 1703462528114626562
}

PUT /your_index/_doc/2
{
  "myid": "1",
  "ts_id": 1703462528114626560
}

PUT /your_index/_doc/1
{
  "myid": "1",
  "ts_id": 1703462528114626561
}


GET /your_index/_search
{
  "size": 3,
  "sort": [ { 
     "ts_id": {"order": "desc"}
  }],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "term": { "myid": "your_value" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}

result has wrong order:
eg:
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 9,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {... "ts_id": 1703462528114626562, "_shard":"202406[0]"},
      {... "ts_id": 1703462528114626560, "_shard":"202406[0]"},
      {... "ts_id": 1703462528114626561}, "_shard":"202406[1]",
    ]


Can anyone help me understand why this might be happening and how I can ensure the results are returned in the correct order?

Update: I have added additional information to the description, particularly specific numbers that were used for sorting. Previously, I had added smaller ones for simplicity. It turns out that their size is significant.
It turns out that the sorting problem is due to the large number in ts_id. In the documentation, it says long 2^63-1, but it looks like the problem might be related to JavaScript or JSON.
I added a query that replicates the problem. I am doing the query in the dev tools.
ts_id in the database looks correct (it is not truncated). I still do not understand whether the problem lies in the encoding of PUT or GET, or maybe inside the sorting engine.

you have sort descending. you want ascending?

I want descending but got 6, 4, 5. I expecting 6, 5, 4

In the hits, what is the content of the sort array for each of these records?

the sort array contains the same values each. eg. "sort": [346] "sort": [344] "sort": [345]

Is "your_index " a single index or do you have multiple indices with slightly different mappings for ts_id (for example long in one index and int in an earlier index). Which version of opensearch are you using?

Normally, I have an index for each month. However, for this query, I am using a single index. Opensearch 2.11.0

In 2.7 opensearch team rolled out some sort optimizations that led to all sorts of interesting bugs and regressions, some of which were fixed in follow up releases. I cannot find any indication of this particular bug, but if I was in your position I would have tried upgrading to the newest version and if bug is still there I would report it to the opensearch maintainers, or better yet just switch to the real thing.

@imotov I started to think that sorting is done per shard and there is no sorting after combining the data. Maybe this is the case?

That would be a pretty bad bug. I wasn't able to find such bug in the list of opensearch issues except for the case where these shards are from different indices with different mappings for this field. If you add  "explain": true, to your query you will be able to see if the result come from the same shard or different shards... or just switch to elasticsearch, I haven't seen such level of bugs in elasticsearch for many many years now.

@imotov I've added shard information to the description. What I meant about cross-shard sorting is that maybe this is how it works and it is not a bug. Maybe I should use routing both when inserting and searching, which I tested and it works. Correct me if I'm wrong. Anyway maybe there is something with sort optimization because it worked for 2 years and after the upgrade opensearch stopped

Do you have a compact reproduction of this issue that you can share? It looks like a really bad bug to me. It's pretty basic functionality, which shouldn't require routing on a properly implemented sorting.

You might be hitting this issue as your ts_id values are 61 bits long. Also interesting to note that if you test the same example with only one primary shard, results are correctly sorted. I would probably report this to OpenSearch.

Disclaimer:
Not a proper answer.
I have done my test on elasticsearch, I'll spin up an opensearch cluster later.
TLDR;
On elasticsearch 8.14.x the sorting works just fine.
Although the Dev Tools display surprising values
Kibana's behaviours
This is the result I get from a search in Kibana's dev tools:
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": { "total": 1, "successful": 1, "skipped": 0, "failed": 0 },
  "hits": {
    "total": { "value": 3, "relation": "eq" },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "78587377",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": { "ts_id": "1703462528114626562" },
        "fields": { "ts_id": [1703462528114626600] },
        "sort": [1703462528114626600]
      },
      {
        "_index": "78587377",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": { "ts_id": "1703462528114626561" },
        "fields": { "ts_id": [1703462528114626600] },
        "sort": [1703462528114626600]
      },
      {
        "_index": "78587377",
        "_id": "0",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": { "ts_id": "1703462528114626560" },
        "fields": { "ts_id": [1703462528114626600] },
        "sort": [1703462528114626600]
      }
    ]
  }
}

fields and sort are containing a rounded value, while the _source is correct.
But I could narrow down this issue to JSON handling in kibana.
As when I perform the same query via a terminal I get:
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": { "total": 1, "successful": 1, "skipped": 0, "failed": 0 },
  "hits": {
    "total": { "value": 3, "relation": "eq" },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "78587377",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": { "ts_id": "1703462528114626562" },
        "fields": { "ts_id": [1703462528114626562] },
        "sort": [1703462528114626562]
      },
      {
        "_index": "78587377",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": { "ts_id": "1703462528114626561" },
        "fields": { "ts_id": [1703462528114626561] },
        "sort": [1703462528114626561]
      },
      {
        "_index": "78587377",
        "_id": "0",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": { "ts_id": "1703462528114626560" },
        "fields": { "ts_id": [1703462528114626560] },
        "sort": [1703462528114626560]
      }
    ]
  }
}

To Reproduce:
DELETE /78587377

PUT /78587377
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ts_id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "myid": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT 78587377/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"myid":"2","ts_id":"1703462528114626562"}
{"index":{"_id":0}}
{"myid":"0","ts_id":"1703462528114626560"}
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"myid":"1","ts_id":"1703462528114626561"}

GET /78587377/_search
{
  "size": 3,
  "sort": [ { 
     "ts_id": {"order": "desc"}
  }],
  "_source": "ts_id",
  "fields": [
    "ts_id"
  ]
}

